# Can I buy 7-day travel card using credit on Oyster card?

Tags: public-transport, london, oyster-card

I got an Oyster card from my family which is topped up with 42 pounds. Actually I was thinking of buying a 7-day travel card once I arrive in London. Can I buy or top up 7-day travel card using that credit already charged on the Oyster card?

Comment: The daily and weekly caps mean that the Travelcard is usually not a good idea, unless you're going somewhere that it specifically discounts (e.g. Emirates Air Line) and making a lot of journeys. It could be a good idea if your week is not Monday-Sunday though.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: The weekly (Mon-to-Sun) cap applies only to contactless, not to Oyster.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Aha! I learned something new today. Thank you. I'm so glad I have a contactless card... :)

Comment: I think the "answer" is no under self-service ticket machines, but yes with the intervention of a staff (by the means of a refund + repurchase). No evidence to substantiate my claim, and hence posting as a comment.

Comment: @B.Liu Thank you for the comment! Maybe I'm going to bring it to the visitor centre in Victoria Station and ask for help.

Comment: There are few if any ticket offices at underground stations these days but there should always be staff near the barriers who, if it is possible to do what @B.Liu suggests, will have the required magic powers to do it at a machine. They link my National Rail Senior card to my Oyster card at the ticket machines for instance.

Comment: @Lindon How much credit is left on the Oyster card?

Comment: @Coke The OP did suggest in the question that it has 42 pounds in there, which precludes a refund in a self-service ticket machine (but possible with intervention of a staff).

Answer (score 3):

If you have 10 pounds or less on your Oyster card, if you cancel it (at a vending machine in the Underground) you'll get the credit and the 5-pound deposit fee refunded in cash (so up to 15 pounds).

You can then use that money towards buying a new Oyster card (at the same vending machine) with a 7-day Travelcard on it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can really transfer money from an Oyster card to another travel card. But if you don't need your Oyster card anymore, you can refund it and use the money then to buy the travel card.

Comment: 7-day Travelcards are electronic tickets that need to be stored on a physical Oyster card. It's not an either-or situation.

Comment: And your credit will only be refunded if it's 10 pounds or less